# Make a query which adds a column to display the number of repetitions of every items in a table

Tags: sql-server

I need a sql server command, which should add another column in the table consisting of the number of times each element in a specific column is repeated. And I also want the table to display no repetition of the item which is beeing counted .
This is basically my table.

```
Medication_ID   Prescription_ID             Dossage
 12                    1013                 blablabla
 17                    1013                 blablabla
 15                    1013                 blablabla
 12                    1013                 blablabla
 12                    1013                 blablabla
 12                    1013                 blablabla
 12                    1014                 blablabla
 12                    1014                 blablabla
 12                    1014                 blablabla
 15                    1013                 blablabla
 15                    1013                 blablabla
 17                    1015                 blablabla
 12                    1016                 blablabla
```

I want to generate something like this:

```
  Medicatition ID | NumberOfRepetitions
  12                     8
  15                     3
  17                     2
```

Comment: Show us the table structure, sample data and the expected output.

Comment: What you've tried to solve the problem would also help.

Comment: I have edited the post , I hope you understand what I am trying to do now

Answer (score 2):

This is simple grouping:

```
select medication_id, count(*) as numberOfRepetitions
from TableName
group by medication_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a query to show those data instead of storing them in your table, If you want to show those columns in side of your table data you can use this query:

```
SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Medication_ID) AS NumberOfRepetitions
FROM
    yourTable
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding a computed column:

```
alter table TableName add NumberOfRepetitions as (myUDF())
```

More information in [this blog post.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/11/28/a-computed-column-defined-with-a-user-defined-function-might-impact-query-performance.aspx)

Or, you could probably accomplish this with a trigger.

Comment: This probably can be done with view:
CREATE VIEW MyView 
AS 
    SELECT T.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME A WHERE A.MEDICATION_ID = T.MEDICATION_ID) AS NUMBEROFREPETITIONS
FROM TABLENAME T